# jQuery: randomize fading divs (regardless number of items)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, fadein

I have this snippet which makes my divs "slide" every 3 seconds:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein > :first-child').fadeOut().next('p').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});

<div class="fadein">
    <p><img src="">image1</p>
    <p><img src="">image2</p>
    <p><img src="">image3</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to randomize the order of divs shown.. the problem is that the number of divs isn't going to be the same every time.. so I can't use

```
setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  ...
```

As it's not always going to be 3.. and I can't change the script every time. Can you help me?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/4/

Comment: Why don't you replace 3 with `$('.fadein > p').length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [jQuery Length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property. It'll get the amount divs you have and you can use the `Math.random` function like you want to.

**Edit**

I've edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/775pR/1/) to make it do what I think you want. There's a little problem with it sometimes showing the same picture a few times in a row but I'll let you decide how you want to  handle it.

Here's the code as well

```
$(function () {
$('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    var randomize = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.fadein > p').length);
    $('.fadein > p').fadeOut();
    $('.fadein > :nth-child(' + randomize + ')').fadeIn();
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Any hint on how to avoid repeating the same rand number twice in a row?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno You could try creating some variable to store the last number generated and when you call `Math.random()` if that number equals the last number you generated you call it again otherwise you set the variable to the new number. There might be better approaches but that's the first thing I thought of.